# How to call pgQuery from postgresql-query?

Tags: postgresql, haskell

Could somebody show me an example how to execute a query with `pgQuery` from this [postgresql-query](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-query-3.4.0/) library? I created a function like this:

```hs
doIt :: (HasPostgres m, MonadLogger m) => Text -> m Bool
doIt name = do
  (val::[Only Int]) <- pgQuery [sqlExp|select setting from pg_settings where name=#{name}|]
  return ...
```

but I cannot understand how to run it. It has a signature:

```hs
pgQuery :: (HasPostgres m, MonadLogger m, ToSqlBuilder q, FromRow r) => q -> m [r]
```

I can execute it with `runSqlBuilder` (to get a `Query` and to execute it with standard `query`/`query_`) but how to execute it with `pgQuery` in `IO` monad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you're supposed to use a [`PgMonadT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-query-3.7.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Query-Types.html#t:PgMonadT) transformer (effectively a `ReaderT` for a `Connection`) to manage your database connection, plus a `LoggerT` for logging.  So, the following type-checks:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  c <- connect defaultConnectInfo { connectHost = "..." }
  x <- runStderrLoggingT . runPgMonadT c $ doIt "whatever"
  print x
```

In practice, you probably want to run most of your program in a custom monad, so something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Logger
import Database.PostgreSQL.Query
import Data.Text (Text)

type M = PgMonadT (LoggingT IO)

runM :: M a -> IO a
runM act = do
  c <- connect defaultConnectInfo { connectHost = "..." }
  runStderrLoggingT . runPgMonadT c $ act

doIt :: Text -> M Bool
doIt name = do
  (val::[Only Int]) <- pgQuery [sqlExp|select setting from pg_settings where name=#{name}|]
  return False

main :: IO ()
main = runM $ do
  x <- doIt "whatever"
  liftIO $ print x
```